# get language on form alter

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, forms

I try to get selected language for specified node (I mean in edit form) on form alter with following snippet in `MODULENAME.module`

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

function MODULENAME_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'node_trends_edit_form') {
        kint($form);
        kint($form_state->getValue('langcode'));
        kint($form_state->getValues());
    }
}
```

BUT    results for   `kint($form_state->getValue('langcode'));           kint($form_state->getValues());` are `NULL`.

how can I get language selected for node on `form_alter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223230/difference-between-edit-and-create-new-node-form/223234#223234) , first try to get `$node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();` then  get langcode with 
            `$langcode = $node->langcode->value;`

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

function MODULENAME_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'node_trends_edit_form') {
        $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
        $langcode = $node->langcode->value;
        kint($langcode);

    }
}
```

**it RETURN EDITING NODE LANGCODE** => en,ar,tr,fr, etc

Answer (score 4):

The code to get the entity language is present in [`language_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21language%21language.module/function/language_form_alter/8.2.x), which you can take as an example to write your code.

```
  $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
  if ($form_object instanceof ContentEntityFormInterface && $form_object->getEntity()->getEntityType()->hasKey('langcode')) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface $entity */
    $entity = $form_object->getEntity();
    $entity_type = $entity->getEntityType();
    $langcode_key = $entity_type->getKey('langcode');

    // Your code goes here.

  }
```

If you are sure the edit form is for a content entity (such as a node), you could remove the part verifying that `$form_object` is a content entity object. I would leave it, but that is my personal preference.

Comment: **not worked**,  `$langcode_key` is null , that means if contents not getting run, but I selected language for that node in form fields.

Comment: thanks for your attention dear kiamlaluno, I submit a answer,it worked for me ,

Comment: Also I tried without if( I bypassed if condition) but `$entity_type->getKey('langcode');` cause FATAL ERROR